# How do you delete, clean or clear a virtualenv in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a Heroku Python project that is emitting errors that I can't reproduce locally. I suspect that the Python virtualenv in the Heroku deployment is corrupted in some way.

Is there a way to clean the Python virtualenv in a Heroku project and start fresh?

Answer (score 1):

See Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime). Create a runtime.txt file with a different version of Python than your current version and push to heroku. This will purge your appication's build cache and virtualenv. Then you can revert to your previous Python version in the runtime.txt and push that up to Heroku, giving you both your desired Python runtime and a clean virtualenv.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to fail if any attempts at new/specified package versions don't compile with the current versions of any packages you specify :-/

Comment: That would be an issue with whichever packages are failing though, not an issue with a particular heroku virtualenv, and thus beyond the scope of this question.